# Cartesian form of vectors calculate the angle

Tags: vectors

Two planes have equations $x + 3y − 2z = 4$ and $2x + y + 3z = 5$. The planes intersect in the straight line l.

$(i)$ Calculate the acute angle between the two planes.

How do you this, I know from the normal form of a vector line is the dot product, what about in cartesian form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the equation of a plane $Ax + By + Cz = d$, the normal vector of the plane is (A,B,C), i.e the vector perpendicular to that plane. Using this you can obtain the two normal vectors, and then apply their escalar product:

$$A_1*A_2 + B_1*B_2+C_1*C_2=|n_1|*|n_2|*cos\alpha$$

where $n_1,n_2$ denote the normal vectors and |·| is the module of the vector.

Comment: Ok, I did this so I got $\vec a = (1, 3, -2)$ and $\vec b = (2, 1, 3)$ then I used the scalar product $$cos\theta = \frac {1(2) +3(1) -2(3)}{|\vec a | * |\vec a|}$$ and I got $\theta = 94.1 $ which is wrong, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your calculations are Ok, however if what you are looking for is the acute angle, note that is not the one you are getting now. if we intersect two planes, 2 angles are possible depending on the direction we took for the normal vectors. In this case we are obtaining the obtuse angle, so we need to do one last step: 180-94.1 = 85.9. Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect, thank you a lot!